# configuring max_allowed_packet for Confluence on AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have set up Confluence on a LAMP stack on an AWS instance and need to be able to adjust the `max_allowed_packet` to install addons. I know AWS prohibits editing the `my.cnf` file and I've installed the RDS client. RDS doesn't seem to see my existing confluence MySQL database for me to assign it to a db group with the larger packet allowance.

Am I missing some option for RDS to see it? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust `max_allowed_packet` by modifying an existing, or creating a new [RDS parameter group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html). You will find many familiar configuration settings in parameter groups. If you haven't touched parameter groups before, you'll likely find that yours is named `default.mysql5.6` (or your version equivalent) and you will need to create a new one to customize your own settings.

You can create a new parameter group from the:

- AWS Console (["Working with parameter groups"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html) describes the creation of parameter groups and modification of individual settings)
- CLI (docs: [create-db-parameter-group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-parameter-group.html))
- API (docs: [CreateDBParameterGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBParameterGroup.html))

You can modify settings from the:

- AWS Console (See above.)
- CLI (docs: [modify-db-parameter-group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-parameter-group.html))
- API (docs: [ModifyDBParameterGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBParameterGroup.html))

When you change from the default parameter group to a custom parameter group, you will need to reboot the RDS instance for the switch to take effect.  After that, you will only need to reboot for individual settings if they have the "static" parameter type. `max_allowed_packet` is a *dynamic* parameter type, which means that the change will take effect immediately once you make it.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have created the new group and updated the max_allowed_packet setting for that group. My underlying problem is that the RDS client is not seeing my existing db for me to add it to the new group.

Comment: @jessc Can you clarify what product you mean when you say "RDS client", and can you verify that it is also missing via any of the methods above? Also, as a matter of site usage, it would be helpful to edit your question to clarify that point -- your "underlying problem" is actually the meat of your question, but it currently reads like a tangential issue... and it isn't clear from the question that you've already set up a parameter group.

Comment: When I refer to the AWS RDS client I'm referring to: https://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-RDS/2928

Comment: My larger question was whether using this client in this instance was the correct route and if so, how I could get it to recognize my existing db versus just creating a new instance to add to my new group. It seems to be working now just from creating the group, but I question whether it will stick after a restart and if it does, I'm not sure why (which will drive me nuts).

Comment: @jessc If "get it to recognize my existing db versus just creating a new instance to add to my group" means that you want to associate your existing RDS instance to the new parameter group, then that can be accomplished by [calling rds-modify-db-instance to modify your existing RDS to be associated with the new parameter group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-ModifyDBInstance.html). Existing instances won't automatically be associated with new param groups.  The instance will need to be rebooted for the changes to apply.